# Using svcutil to generate xsd files for client proxy

Tags: wcf, proxy, svcutil.exe

I am trying to use Svcutil to export metadata for proxy generation off a locally hosted service. I dont want to go into visual studio and click 'Add service reference' as this is a learning exercise on my part(!)

I am using svcutil as follows:

> Svcutil /d:c:\temp /t:metadata http://localhost/IISCalculatorService/service.svc

This then generates two WSDL files, calculatorservice.wsdl and tempuri.org.wsdl. However I was expecting it to generate two .XSD files as well. Without these .XSD files I cant use svcutil to then generate the client code.

Am I missing something in my use of svcutil or is my understading fauly? Any help appreciated.

Here's the service's web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
        <services>
            <service name="CalculatorService.Calculator">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CalculatorService.Contracts.ICalculator" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You can generate the proxy using svcutil <url> and then use the proxy in your project if you do not wish to do it via the Add service reference. If you want the xsd's related to the wsdl to validate something in it then you can simply download it from the specified url in wsdl and add it in your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for service reference directly, you can try this

```
svcutil.exe http://localhost/IISCalculatorService/service.svc?wsdl
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and get an error from svcutil stating "...the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services...."

Comment: Can you browse http://localhost/IISCalculatorService/service.svc and http://localhost/IISCalculatorService/service.svc?wsdl in IE? May be there is some issue with the hosting of your service.

Comment: Yes can browse to them fine. Was thinking that the service wasn't letting svcutil/wsdl see the info it needs

Comment: In your web.config, check this, your service should have one endpoint as <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>, secondly, your service behavior should have  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

Comment: The problem appears to be with IIS setup.
If I host the same service via a Console app, svcutil generates the xsd and the wsdl files fine

Comment: Try hosting your service on Web Server launched from Visual Studio. Secondly is your config same in both Console host and IIS host?

Comment: The config was the same, and I've given up trying to configure IIS for the moment as it's not something I'm trying to learn how to do. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

Use disco.exe to generate XSD files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy2a3ybs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Open Visual Studio Command Prompt and write disco http://localhost/IISCalculatorService/service.svc

Comment: Thanks. This generates calculator.wsdl, services.disco, service.wsdl and results.discomap. (no .xsd files) The MSDN link then suggests using wsdl.exe to generate client code i.e .XSD isnt needed to feed svcutil?

Comment: Is it possible the service is set up incorrectly in the web.config ?

Comment: What is the goal you want to achieve? If you just want a C# proxy to call but don’t want to use the add service reference in VS you can just do svcutil http://localhost/IISCalculatorService/service.svc

Comment: Hi, yes the goal is to create a c# proxy without using VS.