# WCF - generating WSDL and XSD validation file

Tags: c#, wcf

I have some classes (models) and WCF webservices. Can you tell me, how to from these sources generate wsdl file and xsd file ?

Comment: You are asking too broad of a question. You need to show what work you have attempted before we can help with where you are making mistakes. Here are some good reference points to look at: [How to generate a WSDL file from a C# webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340797/how-to-generate-a-wsdl-file-from-a-c-sharp-webservice)

Comment: Thanks, when it comes to xsd from classes?

Comment: Look at the answers here: [Using svcutil to generate xsd files for client proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785441/using-svcutil-to-generate-xsd-files-for-client-proxy).

Answer (score 0):

To generate the WSDL you first need to expose it in the service by means of the HttpGetEnabled property of the ServiceMetadata behavior.

Put the following in your .config file

Once the WCF service is capable of exposing WSDL, you can get it by appending a '?wsdl' to your service url.  For example:

http://localhost/Service.svc**?wsdl**

Once you can access the WSDL, you can generate a WCF client by using the [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (svcutil.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: OP wasn't asking how to generate the client, they want to know how to generate the WSDL and XSDs.